# Is it possible to skip deploy with Skaffold

Tags: docker, kubernetes, skaffold

I'm checking the official documentation on how to skip deploy after build and push the image but there's no clue. Does anybody know how to skip the process?

I even checked the official doc carefully but nothing mentioned https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/

```
> skaffold dev --default-repo=xxx --auto-deploy=false
Listing files to watch...
 - laravel-lite
WARN[0000] k8s/*.yaml did not match any file
Generating tags...
 - laravel-lite -> xxx:841ae56-dirty
Checking cache...
 - laravel-lite: Found Remotely
Starting test...
Tags used in deployment:
 - laravel-lite -> xxx:841ae56-dirty@sha256:d8923a672f61cad9eda2ba19e7fe91822cf5d60444ed955980f1f713b5acc365
Starting deploy...
WARN[0000] k8s/*.yaml did not match any file
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
Deployments stabilized in 26.846882ms
Press Ctrl+C to exit
WARN[0000] k8s/*.yaml did not match any file
Watching for changes...
WARN[0001] k8s/*.yaml did not match any file
^CCleaning up...
WARN[0033] k8s/*.yaml did not match any file
 - No resources found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skaffold dev --render-only=true` should do what you're looking for.

(I'm a bit surprised that we support `dev --render-only` since `skaffold dev` is really meant for a rapid compile-deploy-edit cycle, sometimes called the *innner loop*, and the *deploy* is generally considered an essential part of that loop.)

Comment: @Toshi: we're likely going to remove this option as it was added in error and doesn't make sense for dev.  Could you please open an issue and describe what and why you are wanting to use `dev` without a deploy?  We'd like to understand your usecase! https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/new